# Destroying minions with extra power

Tags: smash-up

In SmashUp game:

When you have a minion that gets extra power, like the war raptor who gets +1 for every other war raptor including himself:

- What is the power score that you use to determine if the minion can be destroyed?

If there's only one war raptor, it's total power is 3, while its base is 2. Then could the opponent destroy it with a card of 'destroy a minion of power 2 or less' ? or i would have to be power 3 or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the current modified stats, not the base stats printed on the card.**

In your particular case, it would require a "Destroy a minions of power [3] or less" card. From the [FAQ](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/08/SU-FAQ.pdf),

> *Q: "Destroy a minions of power [X] or less." Does [X] refer to a minion's base power (i.e. what's printed on the card) or the minion's current power?*
>
> **A: Current (i.e. modified) stats.**